# SignalR StockTicker example not working

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, signalr

Hello and thanks for trying to help :).

I am currently attempting to learn basic signalR so I downloaded the library with NuGet to an existing application to test it out.

The existing app is written in VB (not sure if thats a problem or not)

Error im receiving is "ticker is undefined" which from what I understand is the connection string.

Now Ive read that it MIGHT be the hubs dir which seems to be working fine.  So i'm stuck.  Any idea's would be great.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out.  Turned out that because the app was written in vb I had to add a cs code to the app code folder and then map it in the web.config.

Comment: could you provide a code sample of how you fix this? i'm getting the same error and i dont follow your solution. thanks =)

Comment: instead of using the nuget package installer (http://nuget.org/packages/SignalR.Sample), i pulled the latest from github (https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR-StockTicker) and it worked

Answer (score 0):

For me this was solved because i wasn't including the auto generated file "../signalr/hubs"